# Silverlight ListBox involving Polygons - Exception and Failure when Scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I currently have two ListBoxes in my application which function in a very similar manner. The problem is that one works properly, and the other does not. The one which displays the issue is this one:

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,35,10,5" Name="shapeEncodingListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="225" Style="{StaticResource EncodingListBoxStyle}" BindingValidationError="shapeEncodingListBox_BindingValidationError">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Show Items" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Hide Items" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
                    <toolkit:Separator/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Isolate Items" Click="MenuItem_Click_2" />
                    <toolkit:Separator/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Select Items" Click="MenuItem_Click_3" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource EncodingListBoxItemPanelStyle}">
                        <Polygon Points="{Binding Shape}" Style="{StaticResource EncodingListBoxItemShapeIndicatorStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="encodeShapePanelLegend" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource EncodingListBoxItemTextStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This Listboxs ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection of objects of this class:

```
public class ShapeEncoding
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private PointCollection shape;

    public PointCollection Shape
    {
        get { return shape; }
        set { shape = value;}
    }

    private int index;

    public int Index
    {
        get { return index; }
        set { index = value; }
    }

    public ShapeEncoding(string n, Polygon p, int i)
    {
        name = n;
        shape = new PointCollection();
        foreach (Point pt in p.Points)
        {
            shape.Add(new Point(pt.X, pt.Y));
        }
        index = i;
    } 
}
```

The difference between the two Listboxes is that the working one is bound to a Color-Property, and the erroneous one is bound to a PointCollection-Property.

The ListBox binds the PointCollection properly initally, and the Polygons appear as intended. However, when the ListBox is scrolled down, and then up again, the previously out-of-view items will not appear and errors are generated for each of the items which fail to be displayed. 
The Error and Stacktrace is this:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.
>
> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>     at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
>     at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object >value)
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
>     at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
>     at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
>     at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataCont>extChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs >e)
>     at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated(DependencyObject newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive)
>     at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent(IManagedPeer oldParent, IManagedPeer newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive, Boolean keepReferenceToParent)
>     at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(IntPtr oldParentElement, IntPtr >parentElement, IntPtr childElement, Byte bIsParentAlive, Byte bKeepReferenceToParent, Byte >bCanCreateParent)

I have a suspicion as to what is going on. I have become aware during the course of creating this application that PointCollections in Silverlight are not sharable between Polygons. So is it possible that when the Listbox is fetching the out-of-view items, it attempts to create a new Item in the list with the same PointCollection, which in turn causes the error and failure?

If this is the case, I'm not sure what the best way to resolve it would be. It there any way to keep the ListBox from having to fetch back the Items in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is very easy.. do not "bind" and do not use nothing as data that inherited from  `PresentationFrameworkCollection<T>`...

Logic is simple - DataBinding have to "bind" to data...

Instead of using `PointCollection` use `List<Points>` and convert those points into the `PointCollection` in the "converter"

```
public class PointsToPointsCollectionsConverter: IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var points = value as List<Point>;

        if (points != null)
        {
            var pc = new PointCollection();
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                pc.Add(point);
            }

            return pc;
        }
        else return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

and then bind it like this...

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:PointsToPointsCollectionsConverter x:Key="ptpc"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ListBox x:Name="testListBox1" Width="100" Height="100">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Polygon Fill="Red" 
Points="{Binding Points, Converter={StaticResource ptpc}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

**Just remember. Everithing that inherited from  `PresentationFrameworkCollection<T>` is part of Silverlight UI... do not use it as data...**